# If statement checking for class inputs

Tags: powershell, syntax, comparison-operators

I'm currently still learning, but am working on a small and simple script.
I'm attempting to check the user inputs to ensure they match the desired values of the defined variables. The script works fine, just not quite how I want it to. It essentially confirms the if statement as True so long as atleast one of the conditions is met. I'm wanting it to do the opposite, which is throw a False if ANY of those conditions are not True. Thank you for the help ahead of time. I'm still learning, and practicing.

```
  class Devices {
    [string]$Brand
    [string]$Type
    [int]$zone
   }

$Device1 = [Devices]::new()

$Device1.Brand = Read-Host "Please Enter The Brand"
$Device1.Type = Read-Host "Please Enter The Device Type"
$Device1.zone = Read-Host "Please Enter The Device's Zone"

if (($Device1.Brand -eq "Cisco") -and ($Device1.Type -eq "Switch") -and ($Device1.zone -eq "2" -or "3"))
    {
        Write-Host "Thank You"
    }
    
    else
        {
        Write-Host "That is not a supported device"
        }
```

Comment: By "*throw false*" are you referring to having it in your else block?

Comment: This `$Device1.zone -eq "2" -or "3"` does not work as you might think it does.  The correct syntax should be `$Device1.zone -eq "2" -or $Device1.zone -eq "3"`

Comment: Thank you @Olaf. You should add that as an answer.

(($Device1.zone -eq "2") -or ($Device1.zone -eq "3"))) Worked perfectly. Thank you for clarifying the way that works.

Comment: It is possible to avoid coercing a string to an int or an int into a string. `($Device1.zone -eq 2) -or ($Device1.zone -eq 3)`. Alternatively, `$Device1.zone -in @(2,3)`.

Comment: In short: Something like `$foo -eq 1 -or 2` doesn't work as intended. (It is evaluated as `($foo -eq 1) -or 2`, which in this case is _always_ `$true`, because coercing `2` to a Boolean yields `$true`, which makes the `-or` operation yield `$true`). For the intended behavior, either use separate `-eq` operations - `$foo -eq 1 -or $foo -eq 2` - or, more simply, use the `-in` operator: `$foo -in 1, 2`. The same applies analogously to other comparison operators.
See the linked duplicate for details.